# Proper use of DataRange in ListPlot3D

Tags: plotting, ticks

The user of Mathematica version 9 is trying to plot the following experimental data:

```
data[1]={{{-1., -1., 0.0384625}, {-0.5, -1., 0.068232}, {0., -1., 
15915.5}, {0.5, -1., 0.068232}, {1., -1., 0.0384625}}, {{-1., -0.5,
 0.0477074}, {-0.5, -0.5, 0.0758774}, {0., -0.5, 
15915.5}, {0.5, -0.5, 0.0758774}, {1., -0.5, 0.0477074}}, {{-1., 
0., 0.0123607}, {-0.5, 0., 0.0787931}, {0., 0., 15915.5}, {0.5, 0.,
0.0787931}, {1., 0., 0.0123607}}, {{-1., 0.5, 0.0477074}, {-0.5, 
0.5, 0.0758774}, {0., 0.5, 15915.5}, {0.5, 0.5, 0.0758774}, {1., 
0.5, 0.0477074}}, {{-1., 1., 0.0384625}, {-0.5, 1., 0.068232}, {0.,
1., 15915.5}, {0.5, 1., 0.068232}, {1., 1., 0.0384625}}}

data[2]={{{-1., -1., 0.0384625}, {-0.5, -1., 0.068232}, {0., -1., 
15915.5}, {0.5, -1., 0.068232}, {1., -1., 0.0384625}}, {{-1., -0.5,
0.0477074}, {-0.5, -0.5, 0.0758774}, {0., -0.5, 
15915.5}, {0.5, -0.5, 0.0758774}, {1., -0.5, 0.0477074}}, {{-1., 
0., 0.0123607}, {-0.5, 0., 0.0787931}, {0., 0., 15915.5}, {0.5, 0.,
0.0787931}, {1., 0., 0.0123607}}, {{-1., 0.5, 0.0477074}, {-0.5, 
0.5, 0.0758774}, {0., 0.5, 15915.5}, {0.5, 0.5, 0.0758774}, {1., 
0.5, 0.0477074}}, {{-1., 1., 0.0384625}, {-0.5, 1., 0.068232}, {0.,
1., 15915.5}, {0.5, 1., 0.068232}, {1., 1., 0.0384625}}}

mylist = data[1] + data[2];

list = Flatten[mylist, 1];

ListPlot3D[list]
```

It gives the following plot result,
[image]

However, the x and y axis needs to be scaled because data values for x and y were from 0 to 1.   But when adding two data to get the sum of z values, x and y were added as well.  Therefore attempt was made to use DataRange to scale x y back to original value or from 0 to 1 for both x and y axis.  However, when typing the correct last line of code which is,

```
ListPlot3D[list, DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

the output is

[image]

Cannot figure out what is wrong with the code.  It is giving me the burnout.
Any comments?

Comment: You can add `PlotRange->All` to get rid of the flat chopped off area, but it is still strange.  I get something different that what you get, but it is still strange.

Answer (score 1):

`DataRange` typically is used with arrays of height values, not with arrays of position and height values.  Look at the last examples under "Examples>Options>DataRange" in the documentation of `ListPlot3D` to see how it interprets `DataRange` with arrays of position and height values.  This is not what you want here.  Instead, use `Map` to discard the position values and plot just the height values.

```
 ListPlot3D[Map[Last, mylist, {2}], DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]

as desired.  Incidentally, from the original position data, I would expect that you would wish to use `DataRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}`.

**Addendum**

Relabeling tick marks also works.

```
ticks[min_, max_] := {Range[min, max, (max - min)/2], Range[0, 1, .5]} // Transpose
ListPlot3D[list, Ticks -> {ticks, ticks, Automatic}]
```

[image]